# How to find the 3rd bit of a number

Tags: c++, bitset

I have a question with a problem in c++.
I have to create a program where I have to create one variable from Int and to cout<< on the screen "True" if the 3rd bit is 1.

My question is: How can I see what is the 3rd bit of that number; I've tried with bitset, but couldn't solve it. Please help me.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<bitset>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int x; cin >> x;

if (x % 3 != 0 && bitset<32>(1)[2])
{
    cout << "TRUE";
}
else
{
    cout << "FALSE";
```

}
This should do it right ?

Comment: you mean the third bit from left or right?

Comment: *"I've tried with , but couldn't solve it"*. Tried with what? Tried with what???

Comment: The task is if that variable can't be divide by 3 and the 3rd bit is 1 then to show True. From left to right, after the decimal vergule.

Comment: @JohnFilleau I tried with bitset, but I don't know how it works

Comment: Assuming you mean first bit being least significant one, then third bit has index 2 and you get it via `number >> 2 & 1`. If first one is most significant one, then you need to shift  a bit more, considering the size of the type: `number >> sizeof(number) * CHAR_BIT - 3 & 1`.

Comment: So, where exactly did you get stuck with the [constructor No 2 here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/bitset) and [the bit access operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/operator_at)? Please post your code.

Comment: just do a bitwise-and (& symbol) with the mask 0x0004

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking if a given bit is set is a classic pattern that you will encounter in a great many codebase. So even if there are cleaner ways to do it in modern C++, it's still worth being able to at least recognise the old school pattern when it pops up:

```
// You will typically see bit masks predefined in constants or an enum.
enum flags {
  FEATURE_1 = 1 << 0,  // first bit
  FEATURE_2 = 1 << 1,  // second bit
  FEATURE_3 = 1 << 2,  // third bit
  FEATURE_4 = 1 << 3,  // fourth bit
};

if(value & FEATURE_3) {
  // the bit is set
}
else {
  //the bit is not set
}
```

Explanation:

`(1 << bit_index)`: This creates a mask. I.E. a value with only the bit we care about set. E.G. `1 << 3` is `0b00001000` as a 8 bit integer.

`val & mask`: This does a binary AND between the value and the mask, which will be 0 if and only if the bit is not set. Since any non-zero value is a `true`, we just use the result of the `&` as condition.

You could also shift the value and compare against `1`, but doing it the other way around has the advantage that the mask can often be precomputed during compilation, so the check becomes a simple binary AND at runtime.

Nowadays, it is neater to do so with `std::bitset`:

```
// Replace 4 with the number of meaningful bits
// N.B. index is still 0-based. 1 means the second bit.
if(std::bitset<4>(value).test(2)) {
  // the bit is set
}
else {
  //the bit is not set
}
```

Comment: `1 << bit_index`? (`1 >> bit_index` is `0` for `bit_index > 0`.)

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek Thanks, dumb mistake on my part.

Comment: `\\ Replace [...]` – meaningful and independent of type would be `sizeof(value)*CHAR_BIT`.

Comment: @Aconcagua I disagree. If an `int` is meant to represent 12 logical flags, it's better to use `std::bitset<12>`. This way, you can get error checking on your test hitting meaningful bits.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I have understand it. @Frank

Comment: @Frank Oh, didn't consider that case – good point. Consider my comment as *'Apart from [...]', then it gets valid again ;)

Answer (score 0):

It depends if "third bit" is the third bit from the left or from the right. In either case I would use bit shifting (`>>` operator) to move the "third bit" to the first position and than use AND (`&` operator) with `1`. If the bit is set, AND will return 1, if the bit is not set, AND will return 0.

In pseudocode:

```
x = 0b1011101
          ^ counting this one as the third bit
x = x >> 2 (x is now 0b10111)
is_third_bit_set = x & 1
```

And will return `1`, as:

```
  10111
& 00001
-------
  00001
```